# git filter-branch - WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/filter-branch' is unchanged

Tags: git

I have searched other answers and they aren't helping.

I need to remove a large file across my entire Git history.  I am using `tree-filter` to get rid of this, and I have create a test branch called `tree-filter` to execute this on.

The command I am running is:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f 'wingswatch-api/Data/ntsb.sqlite'" HEAD`

I run this at the top level of the project.

My full path to the file I want to remove is:

`repos\wingswatch-api\wingswatch-api\Data\ntsb.sqlite`

The top level is `repos\wingswatch-api` so I pass it the rest of the path to get into the right folder.

The command returns with:

```
Rewrite d459e0063f989ed4b4ea19c5e8d8f435e177f978 (62/62) (46 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/filter-branch' is unchanged
```

No matter what I pass to the command, it returns unchanged.  Am I missing something?

git version 2.34.1.windows.1 under MINGW64.

Comment: Why you want to do that? Like removing it from entire history?

Comment: @ZahidKhan I need to remove a particular large file.  Following directions here:  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit

Comment: I recommend filter-repo instead. Filter-branch is pretty much dead at this point. Even GitHub no longer recommends it. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: Also you seem in some doubt about the pathname here. You can use ls-files to help you.

Comment: @matt I did attempt to use this but it results in a further error I have not been able to diagnose.  `Unable to create process using 'usrbinenv python3 git-filter-repo.py --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M --refs master~36..master'`.  I have Python 3.7 installed and in my PATH.

Comment: Well then maybe you should be asking about that. Also this may be the wrong forum? Tool installation is not programming. You might get better help on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @matt Well aware of the tooling issue vs. programming (2 decades+ into this) but programmers use git all the time and have to unwind bad commits.  I have simply not been able to get these commands to execute.  It would seem more helpful here.

Comment: Your setup looks correct. What does `git log HEAD -- wingswatch-api/Data/ntsb.sqlite` produce? These should be the commits that would be rewritten by that filter-branch. Given the error you got for Python, it looks like something's gone wrong with some kind of /-vs-backslash thingy on your system.

Comment: @torek That exact command responds with nothing.  Nothing has changed though as I have nothing uncomitted, but have 30 commits waiting to be pushed.

Comment: Interesting. The fact that nothing gets printed shows that the given path name occurs in none of the commits reachable from `HEAD` (at least one must be a root commit so the file would be at least added once); if that's the case, that also explains the behavior of `git filter-branch`. But clearly you believe that there are commits that contain that path, reachable from HEAD.

Comment: Try `git filter-branch -f`.